# Running shapeit for imputation in a linux cluster : GLIBC not found

Tags: linux, libstdc++

As I am trying to run `Shapeit` for `GWAS` imputation in a linux cluster, I've runned into this error message

```
/net/userpath/bin/shapeit: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /net/userpath/bin/shapeit)

/net/userpath/bin/shapeit: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /net/userpath/bin/shapeit)
```

When I run strings `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC`
I get

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
```

Any idea how to get the rest of `GLIBC_*` into the linux cluser ?

Answer (score 0):

This command will install required libraries for the same.

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Comment: I am not an on the list of authorized sudoers.
so I think there is no other way, than contacting the linux cluster "manager"